# MySQL query is working in phpmyadmin, but not in php-code on website

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

The following code  doesn't work after I changed the domain.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `sales` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20"; 
$sqlresult = $mysqli->query($sql);
while ($zeile = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlresult, MYSQL_ASSOC))
     //The Loop does not start :(
}
```

If I use the query in phpMyAdmin, I get 15 results. Why isn't it working?

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't it working"? Do you have error reporting turned on? Also, how do you know you are getting 15 results if the loop never starts?

Comment: On your while loop change mysqli_fetch_array($sqlresult) to $sqlresult->fetch_array();

Comment: What `domain` is changed? Did the query work in PHP prior to the `domain` change?

Comment: If i use the query in phpmyadmin i'll see the results.

Before i changed the domain the code worked

Comment: You have to assure that you are connected to the same database with the same user. I would guess one of those is different.

Answer (score 0):

What does

```
printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
```

return?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Adam Hull (and of course everyone else)!

After changing mysqli_fetch_array($sqlresult) to $sqlresult->fetch_array() it is working. Dont know why but thanks a lot :D!

Answer (score 0):

On your while loop change`mysqli_fetch_array($sqlresult)` to `$sqlresult->fetch_array();`
This is because you are using the oop method of connection to MySQLi not the procedural method please look at 
[The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php)  to fully understand the difference